# Perl one liner in Bash script

Tags: bash, perl, one-liner

I have a bash script that runs, and I'm trying to use a Perl one-liner to replace some text in a file variables.php

However, I would like to check if the Perl one-liner runs successfully and that's where I get hung up. I could just output the one-liner and it would work fine, but I would like to know for sure that it ran.

Basically, the function replace_variables() is the function that does the update, and it's the if statement there that I would like to check if my one-liner worked properly.

I've tried using the run_command function in that if statement, but that did not work, and I've tried putting the one-liner directly there, which also didn't work.

If I don't wrap it in an if statement, and just call the one-liner directly, everything works as intended.

**here's the full file**

```
#!/bin/bash

export CLI_CWD="$PWD"

site_variables() {
  if [ -f "$CLI_CWD/variables.php" ]; then
    return true
  else
    return false
  fi
}

replace_variables() {
  # perl -pi -e 's/(dbuser)(\s+)=\s.*;$/\1 = Config::get("db")["user"];/; s/(dbpass)(\s+)=\s.*;$/\1 = Config::get("db")["pass"];/; s/(dbname)(\s+)=\s.*;$/\1 = Config::get("db")["database"];/' "$CLI_CWD/variables.php"
  if [run_command ]; then
    echo "Updated variables.php successfully"
  else 
    echo "Did not update variables.php"
  fi
}

run_command() {
  perl -pi -e 's/(dbuser)(\s+)=\s.*;$/\1 = Config::get("db")["user"];/; s/(dbpass)(\s+)=\s.*;$/\1 = Config::get("db")["pass"];/; s/(dbname)(\s+)=\s.*;$/\1 = Config::get("db")["database"];/' "$CLI_CWD/variables.php"
}


if [ site_variables ]; then
  replace_variables
else 
  >&2 echo "Current directory ($(pwd)) is not a project root directory"
  exit 4
fi
```

**here's the function where the if statement fails**

```
replace_variables() {
  # perl -pi -e 's/(dbuser)(\s+)=\s.*;$/\1 = Config::get("db")["user"];/; s/(dbpass)(\s+)=\s.*;$/\1 = Config::get("db")["pass"];/; s/(dbname)(\s+)=\s.*;$/\1 = Config::get("db")["database"];/' "$CLI_CWD/variables.php"
  if [run_command ]; then
    echo "Updated variables.php successfully"
  else 
    echo "Did not update variables.php"
  fi
}
```

You can see that I commented out the one-liner just before the if statement, it works if I let that run and remove the if/else check.

**here is the original file snippet before the update**

```
//Load from Settings DB
    $dbuser     = 'username';
    $dbpass     = 'password';
    $dbname     = 'database_name';
```

**here is the file snippet after the update would run**

```
//Load from Settings DB
    $dbuser = Config::get("db")["user"];
    $dbpass = Config::get("db")["pass"];
    $dbname = Config::get("db")["database"];
```

Comment: You probably get an error such as `-bash: [run_command: command not found` because you're missing a space after the opening `[` – but as the answer shows, you don't need `[ .. ]` at all here.

Comment: If you *did* get that error output, that should be part of the question as it's more helpful than "it didn't work".

Comment: Programmatically modifying your code can be a very powerful technique, but for mundane cases, it's often better to have everything in the source file and select which code to run based on a `#define` (in languages with such facilities) or a command-line argument or environment variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### tl;dr and Solution

This usage of `if` with `[ ]` will not give you the result you expect.
What you're looking for

```
...
    if run_command; then
...
```

---

### Longer explanation

#### Basics of `if`

1. `if` is a shell feature
2. based on the condition, it executes the body contained in between `then` and `fi`
3. the "condition" that `if` checks is a command
4. commands usually have a return/exit code. typically

   - `0` for success
   - `1` (common) and everything else for some error

     - e.g. `127` for command not found
5. when the return/exit code is 0, the body is executed
6. otherwise it is skipped; or control is passed to `elif` or `else`
7. the syntax is `if <command>; then...`

#### Where does that `[ ]` come from?

1. `test` is a command that can check file types and compare values

   - refer [man test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) and `help test` (bash only)
2. `[ ... ]` is a synonym for `test`

   - NB the brackets should be *surrounded* by spaces on both sides
   - `if [ -f "/path/to/$filename" ]; then`

     - exception: when terminated by new line or `;` space not required
3. `test` (or `[ ]`) evaluates expressions and cannot execute other commands or functions
4. `if [ expr ]; then` is alternate syntax for `if test expr; then`

PS: good practice to "quote" your "$variables" when used with `test` or `[ ]`

PPS: `[[ ... ]]` is a different thing altogether. not POSIX; available only in some shells. take a look at [this thread on the UNIX Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111)

Comment: thanks, that was way easy. If you can't tell, I'm new to Bash, that did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: i'll be adding the explanation shortly. editing my answer to include it. if you think it all fits neatly, consider accepting the answer to let others know the solution :)